# Open Cognos report in Excel

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have a question regarding opening Cognos reports in Excel.

After saving a Cognos report in a Cognos (Server) directory, will I be able to open this report in Excel? In other words: how can I access the Cognos directory in Excel?

Kind regards,
Edwin

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the more button for the report and choose *run as.*
2. Click on the Excel radio button
3. Press the run button.

It will generate the report as an Excel document and download it for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In your solution, you are still using Cognos to open the file, however I want to use Excel to access the Cognos directory. Normally, when opening a file in Excel you would navigate to your C-drive. Now I want to know if it's possible to navigate to a Cognos directory using Excel to open a file.

Comment: No, mostly because the excel file doesn't exist until the report is run and the query has returned results. You might be able to get the Excel SDK and the Cognos SDK to run the query, fetch the file from where it gets downloaded, and then open it in excel, but what's the point?  Why would you want to spend the time to do that? Of all the things you could be doing, is that the most productive contribution to your company? Then there's the Delmore Schwartz calmly-we-walk-through-this-aprils-day angle; each moment you take to implement that is unique and irretrievable.

Comment: You could use event studio to push the report in an email as an excel sheet.

Comment: You can publish Excel files in the Cognos portal with Cognos for Excel. But I'm speaking here of version 10.x. I don't know if there is a Cognos for Excel version 11.